# Java 8 mapping to sub list entries of a collection using streams and collectors

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I have a collection of `Person` objects:.

```
public class Person {

  String name;

  ChildrenListHolder childrenListHolder;
}

public class ChildrenListHolder {
   List<Children> children;
}

public class Children {
   String childrensName;
}
```

(The entity structure is given by third party.)

Now, I need a `Map<String,List<Person>>` childrensName -> person-list

For example (simplified):

```
Person father: {name: "John", childrensListHolder -> {"Lisa", "Jimmy"}}
Person mother: {name: "Clara", childrensListHolder -> {"Lisa", "Paul"}}
Person george: {name: "George", childrensListHold -> "Paul"}}
```

The map, I need is

```
Map<String, List<Person>> map: {"Lisa"  -> {father, mother},
                                "Jimmy" -> {father},
                                "Paul"  -> {mother, george}}
```

I can do that with a bunch of for's and if's. But how can I do this using streams and collectors. I have tried many approaches, but I cannot get the expected result. TIA.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given a `List<Person> persons`, you can have the following

```
Map<String,List<Person>> map =
    persons.stream()
           .flatMap(p -> p.childrenListHolder.children.stream().map(c -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(c, p)))
           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
             e -> e.getKey().childrensName,
             Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())
           ));
```

This is creating a Stream over the persons. Then each person is flat mapped by a tuple holding the child and the person for each child. Finally, we group by the child name and collect all the persons into a list.

Sample code assuming there are appropriate constructors:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Person> persons = Arrays.asList(
        new Person("John", new ChildrenListHolder(Arrays.asList(new Children("Lisa"), new Children("Jimmy")))),
        new Person("Clara", new ChildrenListHolder(Arrays.asList(new Children("Lisa"), new Children("Paul")))),
        new Person("George", new ChildrenListHolder(Arrays.asList(new Children("Paul"))))
    );

    Map<String,List<Person>> map =
        persons.stream()
               .flatMap(p -> p.childrenListHolder.children.stream().map(c -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(c, p)))
               .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                 e -> e.getKey().childrensName,
                 Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())
               ));

    System.out.println(map);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it does not work. The flatMap call returns `Stream<Object>`, so collecting using `e.getKey` does not work.

Comment: @t777 Hmm I just ran that code inside Eclipse Mars.2 and it worked fine. Which IDE are you using?

Comment: I am using Eclipse Luna 2 (4.4.2)

Comment: @t777 It could be a limitation with Luna then. Could you try with  `stream().<Map.Entry<Children,Person>> flatMap(...)`?

Comment: I just tried it with Eclipse Mars.2 and it work fine for me too. ;) Very strange.

Comment: With that kind of cast it also works this Luna. :) Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

> I can do that with a bunch of for's and if's.

I know that you asked for a stream/collectors solution, but in any case a nested for loop using `Map#computeIfAbsent` works fine too:

```
Map<String, List<Person>> map = new HashMap<>();
for(Person p : persons) {
    for(Children c : p.childrenListHolder.children) {
        map.computeIfAbsent(c.childrensName, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(p);
    }
}
```

and this written using the new `forEach` method introduced on collections:

```
Map<String, List<Person>> map = new HashMap<>();
persons.forEach(p -> p.childrenListHolder.children.forEach(c -> map.computeIfAbsent(c.childrensName, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(p)));
```

Of course it's not a one-liner nor easy parallelizable like in Tunaki's solution (+1), but you don't need a "bunch" of if's to achieve that too (and you avoid also the creation of temporary map entries instances).

Comment: Yes that's also a nice solution. The advantage is that you don't need to have a tuple for holding the children and the person.

Comment: Thank you. I like your solution too. I wish, I could accept two answers. ;)